# PowerShell Retry Loop for fail handling and retry

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm having a bit of difficulty adding retry loop into a Powershell Sharepoint download script and would really appreciate some help with adding to the script below.

What I'm wanting to do is;
If successful, then finish.

If 1'st failure, retry in x seconds (say 5 minutes)

if 2nd failure send email advising there is a problem then finish.

```
Function Download-FilesFromSharePointSiteLibrary()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $LibraryName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $TargetFolder
    )

    Try {
        # Credentials to Connect to SharePoint
        $Username = "Test.User@email.com"
        $Password = Get-Content "C:\SharePoint\SharePoint-Credentials.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $Password)

        # Login to SharePoint Client
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

        # Get Files from SharePoint Site Library
        $List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName)
        $Ctx.Load($List)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        # Get Files from SharePoint Site Library Folder
        $Folder = $List.RootFolder
        $FilesColl = $Folder.Files
        $Ctx.Load($FilesColl)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        Foreach($File in $FilesColl)
        {
            $TargetFile = $TargetFolder+$File.Name
            # Download File from SharePoint Library Folder
            $FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($Ctx,$File.ServerRelativeURL)
            $WriteStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($TargetFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
            $FileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($WriteStream)
            $WriteStream.Close()
            # Delete File from SharePoint Library Folder
            $File.DeleteObject()
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        }
        # Success - End Program
        Write-host -f Green "Success!" $_.Exception.Message
  }
    Catch {
        # Failure - Sleep for 5 Minutes
        Write-host -f Red "Failure!" $_.Exception.Message
        Send-MailMessage -From "no-reply@email.com" -To "Test.User@email.com" -Subject "Failure: SharePoint Connector" -Body "Failure occurred with SharePoint Connector on Server.`n`n$_" -Priority "High" -SMTPServer "smtp.email.com" -Port "25"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
    }
}

# SharePoint Site Parameters and Target Directory
$SiteURL="https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/Test"
$LibraryName="Library"
$TargetFolder="C:\SharePoint\Files\"

# Run Program
Download-FilesFromSharePointSiteLibrary -SiteURL $SiteURL -LibraryName $LibraryName -TargetFolder $TargetFolder
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this, here is one example using a `while` loop. I have stripped your function out of its original code just to show you how the logic works.

Basically, `$Retries` gets subtracted `1` on each loop iteration and if the `try` block succeeds you exit the invocation early with the `return` keyword, else, the logic is tried again until `$Retries` is equal to `0` (`0` = `$false` in the boolean context).

```
function Download-FilesFromSharePointSiteLibrary {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $SiteURL,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $LibraryName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $TargetFolder,

        [Parameter()]
        [int] $Retries = 2 # Retries 2 times by Default
    )

    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

    while ($Retries--) {
        Try {
            # Original code goes here

            # Remove this after Testing
            if (Get-Random -Maximum 2) {
                throw
            }

            # always, at the end of the `Try` block, add a `return`
            # so you exit your invocation here. Essentially, if you got to the end
            # of the `Try` block it means there were no errors, thus,
            # no need to retry anything
            'Success!'
            return
        }
        Catch {
            Write-Warning 'Script Failed retrying...'
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

            if (-not $Retries) {
                Write-Warning 'We are out of retries, sending Email'
                # If we're out of retries
                # Send Mail logic goes here
            }
        }
    }
}

$downloadFilesFromSharePointSiteLibrarySplat = @{
    SiteURL      = 'hello'
    LibraryName  = 'world'
    TargetFolder = 'something'
}

Download-FilesFromSharePointSiteLibrary @downloadFilesFromSharePointSiteLibrarySplat
```

Comment: hmmm. I actually prefer this approach since it gives the user/admin more control.

Comment: @joshobrien my pleasure, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying your code too much, you can increment the amount of times it's ran before calling on itself again using a `$global:` variable.

```
# Description: Download All Files from SharePoint Site Library, then Delete files from SharePoint.
# --------------------------------------------------

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Function Download-FilesFromSharePointSiteLibrary
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $LibraryName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $TargetFolder
    )
    Begin 
    {
        if (-not $global:retriedTimes) {
            $global:retriedTimes = 0
        }
        $removeRetry = { Remove-Variable -Name "retriedTimes" -Scope "Global" }
    }
    Process
    {
        Try {
            # Credentials to Connect to SharePoint
            $Username = "Test.User@email.com"
            $Password = Get-Content "C:\SharePoint\SharePoint-Credentials.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
            $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $Password)

            # Login to SharePoint Client
            $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
            $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

            # Get Files from SharePoint Site Library
            $List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName)
            $Ctx.Load($List)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            # Get Files from SharePoint Site Library Folder
            $Folder = $List.RootFolder
            $FilesColl = $Folder.Files
            $Ctx.Load($FilesColl)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            Foreach($File in $FilesColl)
            {
                $TargetFile = $TargetFolder+$File.Name
                # Download File from SharePoint Library Folder
                $FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($Ctx,$File.ServerRelativeURL)
                $WriteStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($TargetFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
                $FileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($WriteStream)
                $WriteStream.Close()
                # Delete File from SharePoint Library Folder
                $File.DeleteObject()
                $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            }
            # Success - End Program
            Write-host -f Green "Success!" $_.Exception.Message
            & $removeRetry
        }
        Catch {
            $global:retriedTimes += 1
            if ($global:retriedTimes -ge 2) {
                Send-MailMessage -From "no-reply@email.com" -To "Test.User@email.com" -Subject "Failure: SharePoint Connector" -Body "Failure occurred with SharePoint Connector on Server.`n`n$_" -Priority "High" -SMTPServer "smtp.email.com" -Port "25"
                & $removeRetry
                Break
            }
            # Failure - Sleep for 5 Minutes
            Write-host -f Red "Failure!" $_.Exception.Message
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
            Download-FilesFromSharePointSiteLibrary @PSBoundParameters
        }
    }
}

# SharePoint Site Parameters and Target Directory
$SiteURL="https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/Test"
$LibraryName="Library"
$TargetFolder="C:\SharePoint\Files\"

# Run Program
Download-FilesFromSharePointSiteLibrary -SiteURL $SiteURL -LibraryName $LibraryName -TargetFolder $TargetFolder
```

- Added a `Begin`, and `Process` block to implement the global variable of amount of retries.